# Capped collections using MongoDB and SpringData

Tags: mongodb, logging, spring-data

I am trying to create a capped collection for logging using mongoTemplate. However my collection size is growing beyond the size I passed as arguments. Can anyone please help with this.

```
public synchronized MongoTemplate getTemplate() {

    if (template == null) {
        Mongo mongo = null;
        mongo = new Mongo(addrs);
        template = new MongoTemplate(mongo, this.dbName);

        if(!template.collectionExists(HttpRequestEntity.class)){
            CollectionOptions options = new CollectionOptions(4,4,true);
            template.createCollection(HttpRequestEntity.class, options);
        }   
    }

    return template;
}
```

For saving I am calling save on this template instance

```
getTemplate().save(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working after I deleted the collection from mongo console. I guess it was use old meta data as `template.collectionExists(HttpRequestEntity.class)` was returning true.